# why implementing the "call" method when subclassing a tf.keras layer(or model) class makes the layer(model) object callable?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

When writing customized tf.keras layers, we have to implement the "`call`" method, since a object of a class can be called like a function with "()" only(?) if the object has a valid "`__call__`" method. while I didn't find something like

```
class tf.keras.model():
def __call__(self, input):
    return self.call(input)
```

in the keras.model source, how could all this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from keras.models import Model
import inspect

inspect.getmro(Model)
# (keras.engine.training.Model, keras.engine.network.Network, keras.engine.layer._Layer)
```

`inspect.getmro(CLS)` returns a tuple of class CLS's base classes, including CLS, in method resolution order.

The `__call__` method inside `Model` infact comes from `keras.engine.layer._Layer` class. You can refer the code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4343d75c5153470198d970166497fb5b9c4961f5/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L103)

On line [996](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4343d75c5153470198d970166497fb5b9c4961f5/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L1107), inside `__call__` method `call_fn` is assigned as `call` & is indeed called on line [979](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4343d75c5153470198d970166497fb5b9c4961f5/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L979).

So, essentially, in a way I guess, the following holds true -

```
def __call__(self, input):
    return self.call(input)
```

Let's discuss further!

Comment: I was too naive not tracing deeper along the class inheritance path, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You can accept and upvote if you found the answer useful @WenjunFu, so that others could find it