# How passing a whole dataframe (and not only data & label) to Tensorflow's model.fit works - ie how class functions not called explicitly are used

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tensorflow, keras

I am looking at this tutorial: [How to solve a problem on Kaggle with TF-Hub](http://How%20to%20solve%20a%20problem%20on%20Kaggle%20with%20TF-Hub).

I have a problem understanding `MyModel`:

```
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, hub_url):
    super().__init__()
    self.hub_url = hub_url
    self.embed = hub.load(self.hub_url).signatures['default']
    self.sequential = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(500),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(100),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(5),
    ])

  def call(self, inputs):
    phrases = inputs['Phrase'][:,0]
    embedding = 5*self.embed(phrases)['default']
    return self.sequential(embedding)

  def get_config(self):
    return {"hub_url":self.hub_url}
```

I am concerned with `call` and `get_config` functions. Model definition & compilation:

```
model = MyModel("https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim128/1")
model.compile(
    loss = tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(), 
    metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name="accuracy")])
```

When we pass the data to `model.fit`, we are passing a whole dictionary `dict(train_df)`:

```
history = model.fit(x=dict(train_df), y=train_df['Sentiment'],
          validation_data=(dict(validation_df), validation_df['Sentiment']),
          epochs = 25)
```

To process this, it seems that `call` is needed. When is this step done?

I am used to to `train` and `label` data being passed to `model.fit`, as being done for example [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate) or [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/cnn). I am curious why in the above instance passing the whole dataframe works, and I think it has to do with understanding how the `call` function is called.

Comment: "it seems that call is needed. When is this step done?" I don't understand your confusion: the `call` method has been explicitly implemented in `MyModel` class. As for passing the data frame, note that the dataframe is being converted to dictionary and then it's passed to `fit` method. This is completely valid with sub-classed models as well as other models (in the latter case, only if the same names as dictionary keys have been assigned to input layers).

Comment: Further, studying the [relevant part](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models#the_model_class) in documentation may resolve your confusion about model subclassing and its methods.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63008991/why-implementing-the-call-method-when-subclassing-a-tf-keras-layeror-model-c/63011508) question relevant to you?

Comment: @today: Thanks. Yes, it is converted to a dict. When MyModel is initialized, only the __init__ function is called, as I understand it. Then a dictionary is passed to model.fit, and I don't get how my model knows that it is supposed to train for the values within Phrase key of the dictionary, and not for example SentimentLabel.

Comment: @Mishra, it might be, but I don't see a deep connection.

Comment: @today, that reference is quite good, thanks.

Comment: @zabop Because in the `call` method only the `Phrase` data is used (i.e. `phrases = inputs['Phrase'][:,0]`) and not the `SentimentLabel`. Since it's not used, it would be ignored. As simple as that. In other words, it does not contribute to any computation in the graph.

Comment: Alright, that's good. What I don't get is how my model knows that is has to use the call method, if it is not in the `__init__` part of the class defintion (this is probably a stupid question, sorry about that).

Comment: @zabop That's how `fit` method works. Basically either of `model(input_data)` or `model.fit(input_data, labels, ....)` under the hood invoke the `call` method. The answer which is linked to by @Mishra is relevant here.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I think that answers my question. @Mishra, now looked at your answer's links again, it is indeed relevant.

Comment: (Voting to close as duplicate.)